# Difference between update and create&delete deployment option for Azure Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-deployment, azure-management-api

What is the difference between updating an deployment and deleting and then creating a new deployment for a cloud service ?

We have a cloud service set up which during deployment, first deletes the existing deployment in staging and then creates a new deployment. Due to this the VIP for staging is always changing. We have a requirement where we want to make sure that both the PROD and Staging VIP always remains same.

Before changing the deployment option i would like to know what is the real difference and the need to have these two options.

I tried to search but found nothing on this.

### Edit

In the Azure Pub XML, we have a node named 'AzureDeploymentReplacementMethod' and the different options for this field are 'createanddelete', 'automaticupgrade' and 'blastupgrade'

Right now we are using 'createanddelete' and we are interested to use blastupgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Create&Delete deployment the process simply [deletes an existing deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460815.aspx), then [creates new one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460813.aspx).

The other two options do [upgrade deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460793.aspx). The difference between `automaticupdate` and `blastupgrade` are in the value of `Mode` element of the Upgrade Deployment operation. As their name suggests, `automaticupdate` sends `Auto` for that element. While `blastupdate` would send `Simultaneous`. As [per documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460793.aspx):

> **Mode** Required. Specifies the type of update to initiate. Role instances are allocated to update domains when the service is
>   deployed. Updates can be initiated manually in each update domain or
>   initiated automatically in all update domains. Possible values are:
>
> - Auto
> - Manual
> - Simultaneous
>
> If not specified, the default
>   value is Auto. If set to Manual, WalkUpgradeDomain must be called to
>   apply the update. If set to Auto, the update is automatically applied
>   to each update domain in sequence. The Simultaneous setting is only
>   available in version 2012-12-01 or higher.

You can read more on [Update Cloud Service here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh472157.aspx).

Although, if you really want to persist VIP in all situations, I would suggest you to:

- Do not use staging for cloud services at all - just use two separate cloud services (one for production and one for staging)
- use the [Reserved IP Address](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/14/reserved-ip-addresses/) feature of the Azure Platform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the links. I am looking into the reasons behind having 3 deployment options, and which option to use when. E.g. If we have done the deployment on staging and production once, then can't we use ALWAYS 'blastupgrade' option to do our deployment, which will guarantee that VIP doesn't change? Also what are the scenarios in which we have to use the create/delete deployment option ? For the suggestion of not having a staging environment. it's too late for us, as we have this infrastructure set up from almost a year. Any idea how to reserver IP for staging ?

Comment: please read entire documents on the provided references, then ask more questions.

Comment: @astaykon: i have read all the documents, but no where they have mentioned preference between create&delete and Upgrade.
Our team is thinking to move to the upgrade option, but want to know if it has any disadvantage.

Comment: there are only advantages but also some limitations - like you cannot upgrade if there is change in roles or change of Endpoints defined. You also cannot deploy to staging slot if there is change of roles and/or input endpoints defined.